# In Contact form I have a checkbox for subscription to newsletter

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9

The checkbox is checked by default, but I want to uncheck it by default. Can anyone help me over here. As I was new to Magento , I was get the solution for this.
[image: contact form]

Comment: Which contact form please share screen

Comment: In the contact sesion in the footer

Comment: Please share screen where is the check box on the contact page ?

Comment: have seen the image and can you suggest me where can i change to uncheck the check box by default.@Manish

Comment: Which Magento version is it? M1 & M2 are very different. You have tagged it using both

Answer (score 0):

You have to overwrite layout file and need to add your js, in which you will disable the check box by default.

**Here is link**

[Modify Js File In Magento 2](https://erfanimani.com/three-ways-to-modify-magento-2-javascript)

Comment: Can you please explain it in some brief.

Comment: You have to write js to disable the check box .

Comment: Can you give some smaple script and the path where I need to write.